# System.NullReferenceException C# advice?

Tags: c#, exception

I'm getting an exception when I'm trying to run my program.. It seems to me it's working well but I'm missing something as it appears.

```
 public Coord LatLonToUTMXY(double lat, double lon)
    {
        Coord co = new Coord();
        co.zone = Math.Floor((lon + 180.0) / 6) + 1;

        //double zone = Math.Floor((lon + 180.0) / 6) + 1;

        MapLatLonToXY(DegToRad(lat), DegToRad(lon), UTMCentralMeridian(co.zone),       co.eastNorth);

        /* Adjust easting and northing for UTM system. */
        co.eastNorth[0] = co.eastNorth[0] * UTMScaleFactor + 500000.0;
        co.eastNorth[1] = co.eastNorth[1] * UTMScaleFactor;
        if (co.eastNorth[1] < 0.0)
            co.eastNorth[1] = co.eastNorth[1] + 10000000.0;


        return co;
    }
```

I'm getting the exception here ...

```
 public void MapLatLonToXY(double phi, double lambda, double lambda0, double [] xy)
    {
       //Some previous code

       //Exception for xy[0] ....!
        xy[0] = N * Math.Cos(phi) * l
            + (N / 6.0 * Math.Pow(Math.Cos(phi), 3.0) * l3coef * Math.Pow(l, 3.0))
            + (N / 120.0 * Math.Pow(Math.Cos(phi), 5.0) * l5coef * Math.Pow(l, 5.0))
            + (N / 5040.0 * Math.Pow(Math.Cos(phi), 7.0) * l7coef * Math.Pow(l, 7.0));

        /* Calculate northing (y) */
        xy[1] = ArcLengthOfMeridian(phi)
            + (t / 2.0 * N * Math.Pow(Math.Cos(phi), 2.0) * Math.Pow(l, 2.0))
            + (t / 24.0 * N * Math.Pow(Math.Cos(phi), 4.0) * l4coef * Math.Pow(l, 4.0))
            + (t / 720.0 * N * Math.Pow(Math.Cos(phi), 6.0) * l6coef * Math.Pow(l, 6.0))
            + (t / 40320.0 * N * Math.Pow(Math.Cos(phi), 8.0) * l8coef * Math.Pow(l, 8.0));

        return;

    }
```

for the co it's a struct

```
 public struct Coord
    {
        public double zone;
        public double[] eastNorth;


    }
```

What am I missing here ?

Thanks

Comment: There can be a whole bunch of places where things might have gone wrong. The code you've shared is not enough to tell. For instance we do not have get and set of co.zone property. Best is to check your Call Stack.

Comment: This exception most likely happens because `xy` is null. Fix that and you'll fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the `xy` array in your function (which comes from `Coord.eastNorth` is uninitialized.  I noticed that Coord was a struct and not a class.. any particular reason?  This would work if Coord was a class

```
public class Coord
{
    public double Zone {get; set;}
    public List<double> EastNorth {get; set;}

    public Coord()
    {
        EastNorth = new List<double>();
    }
}



public List<double> MapLatLonToXY(double phi, double lambda, double lambda0)
{
   var xy = new List<double>();

   //Exception for xy[0] ....!
    xy.Add(N * Math.Cos(phi) * l
        + (N / 6.0 * Math.Pow(Math.Cos(phi), 3.0) * l3coef * Math.Pow(l, 3.0))
        + (N / 120.0 * Math.Pow(Math.Cos(phi), 5.0) * l5coef * Math.Pow(l, 5.0))
        + (N / 5040.0 * Math.Pow(Math.Cos(phi), 7.0) * l7coef * Math.Pow(l, 7.0)));

    /* Calculate northing (y) */
    xy.Add(ArcLengthOfMeridian(phi)
        + (t / 2.0 * N * Math.Pow(Math.Cos(phi), 2.0) * Math.Pow(l, 2.0))
        + (t / 24.0 * N * Math.Pow(Math.Cos(phi), 4.0) * l4coef * Math.Pow(l, 4.0))
        + (t / 720.0 * N * Math.Pow(Math.Cos(phi), 6.0) * l6coef * Math.Pow(l, 6.0))
        + (t / 40320.0 * N * Math.Pow(Math.Cos(phi), 8.0) * l8coef * Math.Pow(l, 8.0)));

    return xy;

}

public Coord LatLonToUTMXY(double lat, double lon)
{
    Coord co = new Coord();
    co.zone = Math.Floor((lon + 180.0) / 6) + 1;

    //double zone = Math.Floor((lon + 180.0) / 6) + 1;

    co.EastNorth = MapLatLonToXY(DegToRad(lat), DegToRad(lon), UTMCentralMeridian(co.zone));

    /* Adjust easting and northing for UTM system. */
    co.EastNorth[0] = co.EastNorth[0] * UTMScaleFactor + 500000.0;
    co.EastNorth[1] = co.EastNorth[1] * UTMScaleFactor;
    if (co.EastNorth[1] < 0.0)
        co.EastNorth[1] = co.EastNorth[1] + 10000000.0;


    return co;
}
```

Comment: After applying i got a new exception System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: more importantly though, do you understand why it is working and why yours did not?

Comment: I believe I had to initialize the array so it can be accessed from the memory.. other wise it wont have any valid address to get accessed

Comment: Yeah that's basically correct.  You could have kept it as an array, and put `EastNorth = new double[2];` in the constructor as well. Arrays are certainly more efficient if the size of the data structure is known at compile time, but those occasions are rare in the projects I work on.